# Create new columns in pandas df by grouping and performing operations on an existing column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this (Minimal Reproducible Example)

```
thermometers = ['T-10000_0001', 'T-10000_0002','T-10000_0003', 'T-10000_0004', 
                'T-10001_0001', 'T-10001_0002', 'T-10001_0003', 'T-10001_0004', 
                'T-10002_0001', 'T-10002_0003', 'T-10002_0003', 'T-10002_0004']

temperatures = [15.1, 14.9, 12.7, 10.8,
               19.8, 18.3, 17.7, 18.1,
               20.0, 16.4, 17.6, 19.3]

df_set = {'thermometers': thermometers,
         'Temperatures': temperatures}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_set)
```

| Index | Thermometer | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | T-10000_0001 | 14.9 |
| 1 | T-10000_0002 | 12.7 |
| 2 | T-10000_0003 | 12.7 |
| 3 | T-10000_0004 | 10.8 |
| 4 | T-10001_0001 | 19.8 |
| 5 | T-10001_0002 | 18.3 |
| 6 | T-10001_0003 | 17.7 |
| 7 | T-10001_0004 | 18.1 |
| 8 | T-10002_0001 | 20.0 |
| 9 | T-10002_0002 | 16.4 |
| 10 | T-10002_0003 | 17.6 |
| 11 | T-10002_0004 | 19.3 |

I am trying to group the thermometers (i.e 'T-10000', 'T-10001', 'T-10002'), and create new columns with the min, max and average of each thermometer reading. So my final data frame would look like this

| Index | Thermometer | min_temp | average_temp | max_temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | T-10000 | 10.8 | 12.8 | 14.9 |
| 1 | T-10001 | 17.7 | 18.5 | 19.8 |
| 2 | T-10002 | 16.4 | 18.3 | 20.0 |

I tried creating a separate function which I think requires regular expression, but I'm unable to figure out how to go about it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` by splitting with your delimiter `_`. Then, just aggregate with whatever functions you need.

```
>>> df.groupby(df['thermometers']\
               .str.split('_').  \
               .str.get(0)).agg(['min', 'mean', 'max'])
```

---

```
                      min    mean   max
thermometers                           
T-10000              10.8  13.375  15.1
T-10001              17.7  18.475  19.8
T-10002              16.4  18.325  20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `str.extract` to avoid the call to `str.get`:

```
(df['Temperatures']
 .groupby(df['thermometers'].str.extract('(^[^_]+)', expand=False))
 .agg(['min', 'mean'])
 )
```

Output:

```
               min    mean
thermometers              
T-10000       10.8  13.375
T-10001       17.7  18.475
T-10002       16.4  18.325
```